# Ajax loader div in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, jquery

through my application I use common Ajax loader Div, i show it always when i make an ajax request

```
submitHandler: function(form) { 

                $('#loader').show();
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/exampleactions/example",
                    data:{
                    },
                    success: function(response_data){
                        $('#loader').hide();
```

where is the best place to put this div to use it every where ?

shall i put it layout.php ?

Answer (score 1):

IMO

- There is not going to be a 100% correct answer for this.
- Its totally up to the design of the application.

But, if the same loader is used through out the site, and nothing is loaded outside AJAX, then its probably a good idea to keep the div in the layout and keep it hidden until needed.